# tileserver-gl-light doesn't work with leaflet

Tags: asp.net, leaflet, maps, offline, tileserver-gl

I had been using TileServer in Docker successfully, but I needed to switch to TileServer GL Light since TileServer GL native doesn't support Windows. However, with TileServer GL Light, I can only display vector tiles using the following link:

tileserver-gl-light link:
http://localhost:8080/styles/basic-preview/?vector#3.66/23.88/-2.12

code:

```
L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/styles/basic-preview/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
}).addTo(map);
```

Is there a way to display raster tiles in my project with TileServer GL Light?
or i need to edit in the code link to supprt vector or something like this?

[[view in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyZwh.png)]

[[view tileserver-gl-light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjQfA.png)]

Is there a way to display raster tiles in my project with TileServer GL Light?
or i need to edit in the code link to supprt vector or something like this?